# Renaming Account.Type doesn't work

Tags: fields

I've gone under `Rename Tabs and Labels` to rename the standard `Type` field on the `Account` object to something different. It allows me to rename it, but the name is still `Type` on my standard detail page.

Any ideas on how to make the new name show up on the detail page (both view and edit)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I was changing the built-in `Account.Type` field label, and the `Type` field showing on the page was `Type__c`. The built-in `Type` field is not on the page and both fields are picklists and both fields have the same exact label value.

Answer (score 1):

what you have done is right , I just did it in my org and it showed up with right label . I did following :

Rename Tabs and Labels >> Click edit next to Account >> click next >> find type ( there is Type and Account Type ywo fields) >> rename Type to type 1 and save it.

It showed in list views and detail pages.

Comment: Yeh, this is exactly what I did and it did not work. I know it should work, but the fact is, it is not working in my org. I guess I need to open a support ticket.